# Flutter cloud firestore StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> error

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

After updating my flutter plugin i had to update my code because I was receiving error like this 'Firestore' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Class Firestore is deprecated, use 'FirebaseFirestore' instead..

I followed the warnings and update my code but now one my streamBuilders is not working
I don't know why.

here my code

```
class PickupLayout extends StatelessWidget {


final Widget scaffold;
  final CallMethods callMethods = CallMethods();

  PickupLayout({
    @required this.scaffold,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

return (userProvider != null && userProvider.getUser != null)
    ? StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: callMethods.callStream(uid: userProvider.getUser.uid),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.data != null) {
            Call call = Call.fromMap(snapshot.data.data());

            if (!call.hasDialled) {
              return PickupScreen(call: call);
            }
          }
          return scaffold;
        },
      )
    : Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

here is the error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#a2802):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("caller_id")
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>
package:vdb_tinus_app/…/pickup/pickup_layout.dart:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      new Call.fromMap
package:vdb_tinus_app/…/models/call.dart:37
#2      PickupLayout.build.<anonymous closure>
package:vdb_tinus_app/…/pickup/pickup_layout.dart:26
#3      StreamBuilder.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:525
#4      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build
```

This the line with error according to log before updating my cloud firestore plung in it used to look like this   `if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.data != null) { Call call = Call.fromMap(snapshot.data.data);` after updating i had to change it to this   `if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.data != null) { Call call = Call.fromMap(snapshot.data.data());`

Comment: Which line of code is this error referring to specifically?  Please edit the question to be clear what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In this line, `if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.data != null) {`, you are checking whether `DocumentSnapshot.data` is null. Since it is a function (therefore, an object), your comparison never evaluates as `false`.

In the next line, `snapshot.data.data()`, you are calling the above function, whose return value might very well be `null`.

Comment: I am new to flutter can please tell elaborate more on what I must do

Answer (score 0):

In this part;

```
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.data != null) {
        Call call = Call.fromMap(snapshot.data.data());

        if (!call.hasDialled) {
          return PickupScreen(call: call);
        }
      }
```

you should use this part like that;

```
if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.data() != null) {
```

Apart from this project, You shouldn't try to make an video calling app if you are new to flutter. I know that you take this code from a video